# Gesture Detector onLongPress Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Estoy intentando que cuando se mantenga pulsado se vaya incrementando el contador y cuando se suelte se detenga. Lo he intentando con un timer también pero no he hallado la solución puesto que siempre llega a 100.

```
GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: (){
              setState(() {
                 while (_contador < 100) {
                         _contador = _contador + 1;
                 }
             });
          },
        child:Text("+")
)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema que tienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo podrías controlar con un flag, luego un delay de lo contrario no verías como va del 0 al 100.

Algo así :

```dart
  int _contador = 0;
  bool _presionado = false;

  void _update() async {
    while (_contador < 100 && _presionado) {
      // Usa el delay que desees
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      setState(() {
        _contador = _contador + 1;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapUp: (details) {
            _presionado = false;
          },
          onTapCancel: () {
            _presionado = false;
          },
          onTapDown: (details) {
            _presionado = true;
            _update();
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(
                _contador.toString(),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas info de flutter avanzado en mi canal : youtube.com/diegoveloper